# How to use generateStaticParams with searchParams in Next.js 13 (app router) page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

Lets consider this example of fetching first 3 pages of pagination during build time:

`app/listing-params/[page]/page.jsx`

```js
const getData = async (page) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`You are on page ${page}`);
    }, 1000);
  });

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ page: '1' }, { page: '2' }, { page: '3' }];
}

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const data = await getData(params.page);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
```

This will generates routes:

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
├ ● /listing-params/[page]                 145 B          79.5 kB
├   ├ /listing-params/1
├   ├ /listing-params/2
└   └ /listing-params/3

+ First Load JS shared by all              79.3 kB
  ├ chunks/761-dd3b8128e8f09188.js         24.8 kB
  ├ chunks/e7758090-779dc2d147f137fb.js    52.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-50f87aebb0899eed.js    216 B
  └ chunks/webpack-f1b00f9c08769eb2.js     1.64 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

Everything in above example works fine. It will loads 3 routes to cache and first enter on those first 3 pages is instant.

---

**Question**

I'm trying to convert above example to use `searchParams` with ability to cache first routes during build time.
So routing will be like:

`listing-params/1` -> `listing-search-params/?page=1`

`listing-params/2` -> `listing-search-params/?page=2`

`app/listing-search-params/page.jsx`

```js
const getData = async (page) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`You are on page ${page}`);
    }, 1000);
  });

// this generateStaticParams do not fetch data during build time
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ page: '1' }, { page: '2' }, { page: '3' }];
}

export default async function Page({ searchParams }) {
  const data = await getData(searchParams.page);

  return (
    <div>{data}</div>
  );
}
```

During `next build` I see a waring

> warn Entire page /listing-search-params deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /listing-search-params

But I'm not using `useSearchParams` and any `"use client"` component in my app.

Build output looks like:

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
└ λ /listing-search-params                 144 B          79.5 kB

+ First Load JS shared by all              79.3 kB
  ├ chunks/761-dd3b8128e8f09188.js         24.8 kB
  ├ chunks/e7758090-779dc2d147f137fb.js    52.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-50f87aebb0899eed.js    216 B
  └ chunks/webpack-f1b00f9c08769eb2.js     1.64 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

None of first 3 routes are not load to cache during build time and first entry to page `/listing-search-params/?page=1` take 1 second (`/listing-params/1` is instant of first enter).

**Is it possible to load data to cache during build time in Next.js App router (RSC) when using `searchParams`?**

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Comment: @LuisPedroBonomi 
When I find it I will post it as an answer